# Where to find Form tab when making a contactform in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am trying to add a contact form to my page using this tutorial: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-editors/master/en-us/ContentElements/ContactForm/Index.html.

However, I seem to not have the same options as mentioned in the tutorial. For example, when adding a content element I have these options:
[image: My options]

Instead of these shown in the tutorial:
[image: Their options]

I also cannot find the Form tab which is used in the tutorial to add the text fields etc. I only have these tabs:
[image]

Am I using a different version of TYPO3 then the one used in the tutorial? (I am using TYPO3 9 LTS) Or did I miss a step somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked documentation seems to be outdated. This is the core "form" extension prior to 9 LTS.

The documentation for the new form framework in TYPO3 9 LTS can be found here:
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/9.5/en-us/Index.html

The editor to create the form now is in a separate backend module named "Forms".

I'm unsure if the old form extension can still be used in 9 LTS.

Comment: Just realized the new form framework was introduced in 8 LTS. Not 9 LTS.